# Can't send data from JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make a simple JavaScript game, and as a user, I will get a score.
I want to send this score to a PHP server, but in my case, I can't get this data in the PHP file.

Here my JavaScript code:

```js
var obj = {
  "note": 0,
};
obj.note = score;
console.log(obj.note)
var data, xml, txt = "", mydata;
data = JSON.stringify(obj.note);
xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readystate == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    mydata = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for (x in mydata) {
      txt += mydata[x];
    }
    // document.getElementsByClassName("pEl").innerHTML = txt;
  }
};
xml.open("POST", "getnote.php", true);
console.log("true");
xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xml.send("x=" + data);
```

Here my PHP code:

```php
<?php
  // Takes raw data from the request
  $json = file_get_contents('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  // Converts it into a PHP object
  $data = json_decode($json);
  echo $data
?>
```

Comment: check your console, you will see the error (if not, check the network tab)

Comment: no error detected in the console

Comment: check in the network console, you should see the request

Comment: i don't get any information from the network console

Comment: ...at this point, are you sure that this code is been executed? can you post the actual script and possibly the php file?

Comment: ok i will add the code but this is my first application

Comment: Did you mean `file_get_contents("php://input");`?

Comment: this is link where i get the code :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-receive-json-post-with-php/

Comment: after the user play the game  he will get value of his score

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Comment: i have no experience that's why i shared the code and the link

Answer (score 0):

Many people tried to help you, you used a valid sample which you linked, anyway still using the wrong code, which you modified with no reason and all you had to do was to follow suggestions from GeeksForGeeks page you linked.

**Short**
You can not use anything you want when you trying to access `php://input` stream (you used `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is wrong, and I have no even idea why?)

**Working, minified sample**

`test.html`

```
<script>
    let obj = {
        "note": 123,
        "foo": "bar"
    };
    let data, xml;
    data = JSON.stringify(obj);
    xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open("POST", "getnote.php", true);
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xml.send(data);
</script>
```

`getnote.php`

```
<?php
// Takes raw data from the request
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Converts it into a PHP object
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// print whole array decoded from JSON object
print_r($data);

// print single node of the array
echo "The sent note is: {$data['note']}";
echo "The sent foo is: {$data['foo']}";
// etc.
```

Please, read once again [the article you linked](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-receive-json-post-with-php/), also read carefully [the question linked by El Vanja](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18866571/1066240) to recognize what mistake you did.

*Note:* that should be just a comment, and probably will be flagged to delete, anyway I have no idea what else we can do if you don't want to read the simple comments that solve your problem and give you a detailed description.